# display image from table value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with getting two different images to display based on the table value in mysql. Basically if the value in the social_activities table= 1 then i want the 'tick.png' to display and if the value = '0' i want the 'cross.png' to display.

At the moment if the value is 1 i'm getting the cross.png and if the value is 0 i'm getting no image at all. there's clearly something wrong but i dont know what?

Please let me know where i'm going wrong.

Thanks.

```
<?php
            $get_social_set = get_social();

            while ($social = mysql_fetch_array($get_social_set)) 

    // get results from database
    // process results
    if ( $results === 1) {
        $image = 'assets/img/icons/tick.png';
    } else {
        $image = 'assets/img/icons/cross.png';
    }



        ?>


    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30"><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" /></td>
```

Comment: If the value is 1 you're getting `cross.png`?  Looks like you should have been getting `tick.png`.  Where is the code that assigns a value to the `$results` variable?

Comment: it's in a php file called functions.php.

Comment: }
  
   
  
function get_social() {
   global $connection;
   global $profile_id;
   $query = "SELECT *
      FROM ptb_profiles
      WHERE user_id = \"$profile_id\"
      AND ptb_profiles.social_activities ='1'";
   $get_social_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
   confirm_query($query, $connection);
   return $get_social_set;


}

Comment: That's returning the entire record set, you need to extract the desired value from it. Especially as you're doing `$results===1`, which is type checking a record set (array) against an integer.

Comment: you should be checking $social for the values. Do a var_dump($social); to see what the structure is. numeric indexed array or associative index array?

Answer (score -2):

you forgot the `;` after the variable

```
  <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="30"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></td>
```

Also I would use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of that MySQL commands.

also you want to try a `var_dump($image);` to test that you are retrieving the right results

Comment: Statement is implicitly terminated by the close of PHP tag.